# How to set category of every items inside the response in rest framework django?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I have two models like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, default=None, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And have two serializer:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['id', 'title']

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'content', 'created_at', 'category_id']
```

How to prepare response like this:

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Hello1",
            "content": "Hello content1",
            "created_at": "2021-09-25T07:57:23.532416Z",
            "category_id": 11,
            "category": {"id":11 , "title":"Category1"}
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Hello2",
            "content": "Hello content2",
            "created_at": "2021-09-25T08:08:37.984310Z",
            "category_id": 12,
            "category": {"id":12 , "title":"Category2"}
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add a `Category` sub-serializer:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'content', 'created_at', 'category', 'category_id']
```

Comment: I got this error: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `category` on serializer `PostSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Post` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Post' object has no attribute 'category'.

Comment: @reza_khalafi: you should rename the `ForeignKey` from `category_id` to `category`, it makes *no* sense to add an `_id` suffix: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/foreign-key-with-id-suffix.html

Comment: When try to create a post with these data: title:A_POST
content:A_CONTENT
category:1 ,  get this:    "category": [
                "This field is required."
            ]

Comment: I fixed that error through create another customized serializer.